# Ubuntu says...Integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65

Tags: boot, uefi

When I turn on my notebook, it stucks at Acer logo for a while, then works without an issue. My notebook (acer e1-510) originally came with Windows 8.

I did my bootusb with rufus from another windows pc. I tried to install on this machine(just UEFI machine) Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. All is ok. I'm writing from it right now. But each time I turn on my pc, I see the same error on registry: `Integrity:problem loading x.509 certificate -65`

I analyzed with SMART and badblocks my HDD and there is no error. My test was more than 24hs and it's all good with my hdd, so I don't know how can I solve this problem.

Please help me people, I had read about this problem on the site but there's no acceptable answer :(

Comment: Try this: go into the BIOS settings and disable Secure Boot (if you have that option).

Comment: hello!!....I already have disabled secure boot

Comment: @Jonathan can you check from disk utility, does it shows any bad sectors on your HDD